# How do I create new column with random value( random 6 numeric unique - as serials key) into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table in MySQL Database with 8 columns. I want to create a new column. This column will automatically insert a random 6 digit value. Each new entry will be created with a unique value (from 000000 to 999999).

Is this possible?

Comment: @user1844933 A trigger won't work in this instance, because a MySQL trigger can't update the same table that invoked it (otherwise there could be an infinite loop). This task would be better accomplished in the application code.

Comment: sorry because im new with MySQL. Its a part same with ạuto increment but it should to be 6 numeric with random values.

Comment: To my knowledge it's not possible to do so on the MySQL side of things. However, you could easily accomplish it in your application code.

Comment: PHP code or a query with SQL ? Im looking for solution for this. Thx !

Comment: They have to be in a specific order or you need them to be randomly ?

Comment: Hi, i need them to be randomly (6 digit value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think shoud do the job is  :

- create a porcedure that will handle the random data insert and check
  if the values exists.
  **to generate random number**

  SELECT FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 999999) AS random_number;
- create a trigger that will call this proc every time an insert will
  be done !

  CREATE TRIGGER bla_bla AFTER INSERT ON your_table
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        call proc();
      END;//

Comment: Thanks @Up_One, im sorry because im new with MySQL. Im not sure about your tutorial. So i will create new that column by this query "CREATE TRIGGER bla_bla AFTER INSERT ON your_table" and use a trigger for insert randomly values ? is this automatically (with new record create) ? I can create new column by manually and use your query for insert value ? Thx !